# why alert is not display while using service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

i am trying to use $ionicPopup in my service .Actually when I am using in controller it run correctly .please click on button and check
here is plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/wIss45ijr0DfvUVB1GPG?p=preview

But when I used in factory it gives error .Please check error in console.

**Error:Maximum call stack size exceeded**

http://plnkr.co/edit/l3rvPB7AZV1WIRbMEnXd?p=preview

```
ap.factory('utlity', ['$ionicPopup',function($ionicPopup) {
   function showOtcresult(message){
       var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
           title: 'Alert',
           template: message.toString()
       });
       alertPopup.then(function(res) {
           console.log('Thank you for not eating my delicious ice cream cone');
       });
   }
  return {
      showOtcAlert:function showOtcresult(message){
          showOtcresult(message)
      }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is down to same name for two functions which caused loop call

`showOtcresult`

```
return {
  showOtcAlert: function whateverNameForDebug(message) {
    showOtcresult(message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for the name in the function declaration, since it will be executed by calling the property key `showOtcAlert`, so you need to do:

```
return {
      showOtcAlert:function (message){
          showOtcresult(message)
      }
  }
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LchODmtu1xjO6J6p8CDX?p=preview)

Comment: There is a good need for function name if you want to get out from hell of anonymous function while debugging